# Jquery - Get div html from string

Tags: jquery, string

I have a string containing html, including several divs.  I need to get the html from one of those divs, which has the class '.image-desc'.

I thought I would be able to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$('<div class="image-title">Title</div><div class="image-desc">Description</div>').find('.image-desc').html();
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will search for children, not elements in the current jQuery object.

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the current selection:

```
$('<div class="image-title">Title</div><div class="image-desc">Description</div>')
    .filter('.image-desc').html();
```

Working example on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ZEr5q/)**

Comment: Thanks Didier Ghys.  I was almost there :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're writing

```
$('<div class="image-title">Title</div><div class="image-desc">Description</div>')
```

will create a jQuery object containing two divs. So

```
$('<div class="image-title">Title</div><div class="image-desc">Description</div>').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('image-desc')){
             //do whatever you want
        }
})
```

should work

EDIT : @Didier Ghys' answer is neater